# What is difference between "be known as" and "be known to"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, syntax

What is difference between "be known as" and "be known to"?

I think the meanings are same.

is there any difference in usage or syntax..?

Comment: Don't forget _be known for_...   They can all be quite similar.  She is known as an early riser.  She is known to rise early.  She is known for her early rising.  (FYI: _Early Rising_ = waking early to start to the day.)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the main difference is

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[be known as sth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/known)**

> If someone or something **is known as** a particular name, that person or
>   thing is called by that name:
>
> *And this is Terry, otherwise **known as** "Muscleman".*

[**be known to be/do sth**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-known-to-be-do-sth)

> If something or someone **is known to be** or do something, people know
>   that it is true or happens, or that someone is or does something:
>
> *A daily intake of 20 mg of vitamin C **is known to be** sufficient in most
>   cases to ward off scurvy.*

Basically, the first is used when you have an alias or a knickname; the second is used when people know you for something that you do.

Other examples for the second meaning taken from [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/known-to-do-something)

> She **is known to be** interested in pop music.
>
> They **are known to have** spoken to the President about it.

As I have stated below in comments, I've not found references for "be known to [verb]" in general, but seeing the example provided by @joiedevivre, I think that we can say that "be known to [verb]" is practically

> If something or someone is known to [verb] (something, if verb is transitive), people know that it is true or happens, or that someone [verb] something:
>
> *The drug is known to cause seizures.*

The drug is known to cause [verb] seizures [something]

People know that drugs cause seizures. "Drugs cause seizures" is a true premise known by people.

Comment: "Be known as" and "be known to be" are nearly synonymous (with different grammatical requirements). "Be known to" means something else entirely.

Comment: @joiedevivre You may be right. I've not found information about "be known to" by itself.

Comment: +1 Good edit. I do think you're still missing the "known to" others example, though. And also that you can be "known to be" something with the usage "known as." For example, _he was known as a mass murderer._ But your answer is better than mine!

Comment: @joiedevivre Thanks! The problem here is that I'm not English native speaker. I have to back up my statements with references because I didn't know first hand how you use your language. You are right about "known as a mass murderer" but the best dictionary I have found don't mention that usage.

Comment: Well, I admire you for making answers on this site, and I think there's often a lot of value in having non-native speakers answer, too, since I think sometimes you understand the difficulties in learning the language better.

Answer (score 3):

You can "be known as" a name or something else (usually something you'd be famous for):

> He was known as Tom
> She was known as an actress

You can "be known to" others:

> I am known to Tom.

This means, simply, that Tom knows who I am.

However, "be known to" is used more often when a person is not the subject:

> The drug is known to cause seizures.

This means that people know that the drug causes seizures.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when we say **be known as**, we refer to someone's ***identity***. This could be their name, or some defining characteristic about them:

> His name is Robert, but he **is known as** Bobby.
>
> Edmund Hillary **was known as** an intrepid explorer and a concerned philanthropist.

However, when we use **be known to**, we are generally talking about someone's ***behavior***. This phrase is often followed by some action:

> He **was known to** eat the same restaurant every Thursday.
>
> She **was known to** cancel interviews at the last minute.

While I would not call them "interchangeable," there can be a lot of overlap between the two. With just minor adjustments in the wording, we can often express very similar sentiments using either expression:

> Pablo Picasso **was known as** a painting pioneer.
>
> Pablo Picasso **was known to** paint in novel ways.

Also, these expressions are flexible, and I don't claim my definitions here are the only ways these phrases can be used. For example, **be known to** can also be used to mean that someone was aware of something, as in:

> The suspect's violent past **was known to** police.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply:

To "be known as" refers to someone's general reputation, as in 'he came to *be known a*s an angry man'.

To "Be known to" refers to a personal reputation (used when a relationship that has become more intimate), as in 'she came to *be known to* me a loving woman'.

Comment: _She came to be known to me a loving woman_ doesn't make sense. That sentence requires **both** _to_ and _as_. It should be _known **to** me **as** a loving woman_.